# Clash of Clans Troop Donation Count

Tags: clash-of-clans

How is this number calculated?

Is it by housing space or by physical unit? Does donating 5 barbarians count as 5 and 1 golem counts as 1? Or 5 barbarians count as 5 and 1 golem counts as 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the donation of troops it counts housing space and not one per unit.  If you were to donate a dragon which takes up 20 housing space the receiver of the donation would receive 20 single troop worth of troops.

Ex. If the Clan castle were level 3 which can only collect 20 troops, then 1 dragon would fill it to capacity and no more troops would be able to be donated until used up and asked for again.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the number of times someone can give troops to one of his clanmate, then it is counting per unit, regardless of housing space. Unless your clan unlocked an upgrade, you have a donation limit of five units every time a clanmate requests troops. Of course, the housing space is still taken in consideration as you won't be able to donate a unit that is not able to fit in the clan castle.